# Plotting single points on different existing functions

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot 4 different functions, which I manage to do, by using the following code:

```
clear all;clc;close all;

normalDiffuse = [2 7.4567
3 7.1941
4 6.9443
5 6.7455
6 6.5636
7 6.3707
8 6.2483
10 5.9840
14 5.5388
16 5.3825
20 5.0466
23 4.8314];

diffuseWithNoise = [2 7.9944
3 7.9237
4 7.7955
8 7.2938
10 7.1093
11 7.0366];

specularSurface = [2 6.3446
4 5.9177
6 5.8365
7 5.6191];

shadows = [2 8.6936
4 8.5689
8 8.5490
16 8.4074
32 7.7302
33 7.6296];

xmarkers = ;

figure(1);
p = plot(normalDiffuse(:,1),normalDiffuse(:,2),...
    diffuseWithNoise(:,1),diffuseWithNoise(:,2),...
    specularSurface(:,1),specularSurface(:,2),...
    shadows(:,1),shadows(:,2));
%set(p(1),'Marker','o');
set(p(1),'Color',[1 0 0]);
set(p(1),'MarkerFaceColor',[1 0 0]);
%set(p(2),'Marker','hexagram');
set(p(2),'Color',[0 1 0]);
set(p(2),'MarkerFaceColor',[0 1 0]);
%set(p(3),'Marker','square');
set(p(3),'Color',[0 0 1]);
set(p(3),'MarkerFaceColor',[0 0 1]);
%set(p(4),'Marker','diamond');
set(p(4),'Color',[1 0 1]);
set(p(4),'MarkerFaceColor',[1 1 0]);
for i=1:4
    set(p(i),'LineStyle','-');
    set(p(i),'MarkerSize',10);
    set(p(i),'MarkerEdgeColor',[0 0 0]);
end
grid;
legend('Normal diffuse', 'Diffuse with noise','Specular surface',...
    'Shadows');
xlabel('SPP');
ylabel('MSRE');
```

What I am trying to add now is not another function, but single points for each function. For example for the first set of points, I want that on the relative function plot it appears some symbol (a circle for example) on the function itself when X = 4. And so I want the same for the other functions but for other X values. At the end, I would like to add in the legend that particular sign (circle in our case)  as a special value. May you kindly help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hold on` to draw extra features on the figure. For example, you can do:

```
x=1:1:100;
y=sin(x);
figure,plot(x,y)
hold on, plot(x(4),y(4),'o','MarkerSize',20);
legend('data','point')
```

You can then edit the figure, and delete the legend that you don't want or change the text/size